# How to Delete CRL Files in Local Cert Store

Tags: powershell, certificate-authority, crl, certutil, cert-manager

I need to import **CRL files** to a Bastion server that is **not part of my environments domain**. The CRL files are updated every few days so a new copy needs to be imported to the **local cert store** on the Bastion frequently.

I noticed when I do a **fresh import** of a **new CRL** old copies are **not** overwritten or deleted, a **new copy is just added** to the list. I'd like to run a script that will first **delete the old CRL files** in the **Trusted Root CA and Intermediate CA CRLs** store.

[image]

I haven't found a method to delete outdated/expired CRLs using **certmgr**, **certutil** or **powershell**. I need a way to **script** this so its **automated**. Has anybody found a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with certutil:

```
certutil -delstore Root <CRLHash>
certutil -delstore CA <CRLHash>
```

Unfortunately, PowerShell and .NET don't provide built-in means to enumerate CRLs in the store, nor they support CRL objects. If you need totally controlled approach, then you will have to p/invoke Win32 functions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptography-functions#certificate-and-certificate-store-functions, which is a large amount of programming work.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell:
List (I am listing by issuer but you can tweak), one to delete.

Get list of all CRL hashes in CA store:

$crlHashes = ls  HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA\CRLs | %{$_.name.split(" \ ")[6]}

Associate the hash with issuer so you know where it came from:

$crlHashes | foreach-object {Write-Host; Write-Host "Hash: $*"; certutil -store CA $* | findstr Issuer}

Then decide which ones to delete with the same command posted earlier:

certutil -delstore CA < hash >

Then you can automate with an if/then with something like "if issuer = < someone >, then delete"